# TVS with low Vclamp margin

Tags: tvs, clamp

Thanks for your support in this forum.
Currently I have a couple of PCB that I need to provide a double input power supply and transient protection.
The specs for this couple of PCB are Vin= 9 to 17.5V. (12V nominal), consumption is about 18-24W/each (working mode dependent).
Long cable runs and hot plugging could induce transient voltage spikes which may exceed the input voltage limit and I need to protect it.
The system will have 2 VDC inputs, and will be capable to have a hot-swap between them. As you can see in the attach schematic, the 2 Schottky diodes allow to do this, besides reverse polarity protection.
The input battery used could provide up to 16.8V max (10-16.8V range).

I am looking for a TVS Diode (see it in the attach file).The problem I am facing is about the specs in TVS diodes. As far as I understand, Vclamp should be 17.5V, but then, Vr and Vbr are too low.(should be 17V minimum)
Any idea how to solve this short margin between Vr/Vbr and Vclamp? Could I place a Zener to clamp it to 17.5V?
Any tip will be welcome. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Any tip will be welcome.*

The only way I see to solve this is to identify the specific parts in the PCB (currently not shown in the question) that are most likely to be victims to the over-voltage and, assess what protection is **really** needed to prevent those devices failing. Having a continuous specification of 17.5 volts maximum will almost certainly mean that a transient limit of several volts higher than this is likely for well-designed equipment.

So, at the moment, there is too little headroom in your requirements even for a zener to be a solution let alone a TVS. I suggest you analyse the PCB to see at what point a higher voltage (transient) might become a problem.

> *Long cable runs and hot plugging could induce transient voltage spikes
> which may exceed the input voltage limit and I need to protect it.*

It's generally accepted that the worst case scenario will be when you activate the power supply at the source end of the cable. Due to transmission line effects, you might see a peak (at the PCB) of up to double the applied source voltage.

You also need to calculate the transient energy that can flow from the source too so that you can pick a TVS diode that can handle the transient energy without failure.

It's all about threats and victim analysis.

Comment: @JordiNC if we're done here you should [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand the motivation folk have to give free advice. If there are any open questions please raise a new comment but try not to drift too far from the original question OR complete the Q and A session as per the link.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, more information is needed to choose the proper TVS. Unfortunately I haven't yet. This is a device with FPGA and some RF Parts. There is a power supply regulators wich accepts 10 to 17.5V (VDC). But I am don't know about the maximum spike tolerance. I am sure it is well designed. 
Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @JordiNC OK if you are done with this question (hey you can always ask a new related question once you have got the threat and victim info) then you should pick an answer and select it [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png).

Answer (score 0):

TVS clamp voltage (as for any transient suppressor) is specified at the maximum surge current discharging through the device. (see attached screenshots from EPCOS datasheet)
[image]

[image]
If you select an oversized device you get a lower clamp voltage at the desired current level.
Then, there is the maximum voltage of your line to be lower than the lowest triggering voltage of your TVS/Varistor: usually not a problem, unless you select its thresholds too low, because you exaggerate with the desired protection.

Usually, taking the maximum voltage on your line, your ICs and components should be able to withstand at lest 20% more (steady, e.g. during charging). But transient voltage with solid-state electronics is an issue, so your ICs should be always buffered e.g. by a voltage regulator that bears the transient voltage upstream. Otherwise a lot of capacitance...

Answer (score 0):

I've been using TVS diodes for many years.

I bought on ebay a used but professional Electrical Fast Transient and Surge generator to test some parts.

The instrument has an output connector at 50 Ohm.

The instrument generated +/- 4 kV standard signals for 5 minutes.

I tested mainly the PESD1CAN family by NXP.

Here are some hints for you.

1. They were able to protect my circuitry. In short, they worked.
2. My system worked at 12 Volt so I decided to use a TVS with a Vbr of 24 V bidirectional.
3. Even though thr TVS declared a Vbr of 24 Volt I saw voltage peaks of +/- 40 V
4. The thermal camera showed me a yellow spot blinking on the TVS. That meant that the TVS diode deviated energy to ground.
5. The circuitry to protect were made of BJT's which are more robust than CMOS.